# What number goes into both 225 and 100?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I'm doing a bit of algebra/pre-calculus. What would be the highest number that goes into both $225$ and $100$?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes into"?..

Comment: Write the prime factorization of each number and see what factors they share. Did you try this problem before asking?

Comment: See [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)  One approach is to factor the numbers, which is easy here, and take the prime factors that are common.  Another is the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the prime factorization for each one:

$$225= 15^2 = (3\cdot 5)^2=(3^2)(5^2)$$
$$100= 10^2 = (2\cdot 5)^2 = (2^2)(5^2)$$

What is the biggest number that both $100$ and $225$ have in common? That is the answer you are looking for, assuming that by your question, "What would be the highest number that *goes into*..." you're asking for the *greatest common divisor*, also known as the *greatest common factor.*

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate on the method alluded to in Ross Millikan's answer.

The [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) says that $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,m-n)$, where $m>n$.

Thus, write: $$\gcd(225,100)=\gcd(100,125)=\gcd(100,25)=\gcd(75,25)=\gcd(50,25)=\gcd(25,25)=25$$

Comment: What you describe is *not* the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The Euclidean algorithm is based on the fact that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, r)$ if $a > b$ and $r$ is the remainder when dividing $a$ by $b$. Thus:

$\begin{align}
  \gcd(225, 100)
    &= \gcd(100, 25) \\
    &= \gcd(25, 0) \\
    &= 25
\end{align}$